# SQL server 2012 `denali`, new report control

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

What new report controls were added in SQL server 2012?

Answer (score 1):

The new version of SSRS in 2011 is going under the name “Project Crescent” and looks really good. Here is a link to a preview

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2010/11/09/a-glimpse-at-project-crescent.aspx

It was not released as part of the CTP so we will have to wait but I would imagine that there will have to be a new Report Viewer control to handle the new functions that will be released when it goes to RTM

Answer (score 0):

SSRS in 2011/2012 is actually code named "Denali".  Project Crescent is the code name for a new ad-hoc report building/self-service BI tool that leverages Reporting Services.

AFAIK, they cannot release a new version of the control with Denali because it will be out of band with the IDE release (Visual Studio), since VS and SQL have different ship cycles, and the Report Viewer controls ship with VS.

We'll probably have to wait until the next version of VS to get a updated version of the Report Viewer controls for SQL Server "Denali".